# How makes x-overflow render on table instead of window?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

There is a table in link below:
https://www.storm-online.ir/invoice/4YEzvKWkfm8ESqiHFNZfmh

I gave it a min-width in css and overflow-x. But in mobile template overflow-x is not rendered on table.

I need to see the template in correct order in header and footer and just can move table side to side.

code is something like this in simple way:

```
<div>
<table style="">
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>11</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

and css is like this:

```
<style>
table{
overflow-x: scroll; min-width: 600px;
}
table td{
border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
</style>
```

Comment: we can not see the example in storm-online

Comment: Hello, can you please provide some code ? otherwise I'm afraid we cannot help you

Comment: I edited and added some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `overflow-x: scroll;` to parent div of table

```css
 .table-wrapper {
   overflow-x: scroll;
 }
 table {
   min-width: 600px;
}
td {
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table style="">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>11</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If it works for you then tick mark it so others who have similar issue can get the correct answer